# HTTP request to the same endpoint but different query parameters gets overwritten

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have two child components within a parent component. And these components use the same service to get a list of users, which contains this observable which accepts a parameter (limit) that dictates how many users to display (5 by default):

```
getUsers(limit=5) : Observable<any>{
return this.http.get<any>(`http:localhost:3000/users?limit=${limit}`);
}
```

For the first child component (Component A), I'm setting the getUsers limit to **50** on NgOnit, and for the second child component (Component B), I'm setting the limit to **20** on NgOnit.

However, since both of these components are under the same parent component, they are both initializing at the same time, and the requests are getting overwritten. For example, even though I have set the limit to 20 on the second component, it's still returning 50 users.

What could be causing this behavior and how do I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: How did you inject the service?

Comment: @Shuvo I injected it in the constructor privately: (private userService : UserService). Then I called it in NgOnInit like this: userService.getUsers(50).subscribe(data => //code here);

Comment: Did you try to add the `UserService` in the `providers` array of each child component's **@decorator**

Comment: @Shuvo thanks will try this one. I just find it weird, since I even created a duplicate function for getUsers(), so that the components won't call the same function OnInit. But even that seems to overwrite the data that I'm getting.

Comment: By the way, did you use the `@injectable` decorator in the service like this: `@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})`

Comment: @Shuvo yup, the service is working. However the data is being overwritten when doing a request to the same endpoint with different query params.

Comment: Using `providedIn: root` here won't be the issue with the overwriting. Even if there's only one instance of the service, there will be a separate subscription from each of the child components.

Comment: If you post a more thorough code example or StackBlitz I'd be able to give a more comprehensive answer and perhaps point out where it is you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject the service into each one of your child components. When using `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})`, you will only have one instance of this service. However, each child component will still have it's *own subscription* when calling your service.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxlmkf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fchild-two%2Fchild-two.component.html) that shows what I mean.